# Firefox JQuery AJAX: Fetched data is not always displayed

Tags: firefox, jquery

i have following function:

```
function fnGetIdentifiers(id){
    $.get(
    'getCultureIdentifiers.php?cultureID=' + id,
    function(data){
        if (data.length > 0){               
            var identifiers = '';
            $.each(data, function(index, value){                    
                identifiers += value + ', ';
            })                
            $('#identifiers').text(identifiers.substring(0, identifiers.length - 2));
        }
    }, 
    "json"
    );
}
```

the tag identifiers is in this context:

```
<dt>Identifiers</dt><dd id="identifiers"></dd>
```

This displays detail information of the currently selected row in a table (jquery datatables plugin). When selecting a different row the information should be updated. This works perfectly fine in IE8.
However in Firefox 3.6 and 9.0.1 sometimes the dd element is blank even though the ajax request returned the correct data ( verified with firebug). Even more confusing is that sometimes but not always you can for very brief moment see the data and then it disappears again.

Any ideas how this could be resolved?
Note that on row change there is another AJAX request also getting detail data. This one always works also in Firefox. The order in which they are run does not matter. behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always posted this 5 min too early...just before the obvious "epiphany".

The "other AJAX request" mentioned clears contents of all dd elements in the list and since the calls are asynchronous order does not matter. -> the dd element identifiers gets updated correctly (visible by eye) and then the second request which almost always takes longer to fetch data clears it again.
Solution: don't empty identifiers element in second call:

```
if($(this).attr('id') != 'identifiers'){
    //...
```